# Using a collecting hover mower without the collector

Tags: mowing

I have an electric hover mower with a collector, similar to this one:

[image]

I have taken to using it without the collector attached, because I would rather the clippings mulch my lawn, than have to deal with large quantities of collected clippings.

This has the pleasant side effect of making the mower much lighter and easier to manoeuvre, at first. But after a minute or so, the air inlet grating at the top gets blocked with grass sucked from the air, the hover effect ceases to work, and I have to stop, clear the blockage, continue.

Is there an "authorised" method, or a hack (that's not expensive or hassly enough to outweigh just buying another mower) to bring the air inlet somewhere there's less grass flying around? My one idea is to somehow fix a piece of drainpipe or drier venting to bring the air inlet to, say, waist height.

Answer (score 3):

I don't own a hover mower but looking at the design of this mower and other flymo mowers I would try to cut a a discharge hole at the back of the collection box and possibly fashion some sort of chute to direct the clippings away from air inlet.

If you want an authorized answer try contacting Flymo.